# MongoDB on Windows ignoring "<install directory>\bin\mongod.cfg"

Tags: mongodb

output of `ls D:\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin`

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         2023/6/22     17:50           1558 InstallCompass.ps1
-a----         2023/7/12     12:20        1043841 mongod.2023-07-12T04-20-01.mdmp
-a----         2023/7/17     13:28            601 mongod.cfg
-a----         2023/6/22     19:12       56578560 mongod.exe
-a----         2023/6/22     19:12      849137664 mongod.pdb
-a----         2023/6/22     18:36       34941440 mongos.exe
-a----         2023/6/22     18:36      476147712 mongos.pdb
```

part of content in mongod.cfg:

```yaml
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: D:\MongoDB\Server\6.0\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
```

error occurred in MongoDB initialization(Removed irrelevant parts):

```
NonExistentPath: 

Data directory D:\data\db\ not found. 
Create the missing directory or specify another path using 

(1) the --dbpath command line option, or 
(2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file.
```

bin folder path of mongodb has been added into environment variable `PATH`

if I use `mongod -f D:\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongod.cfg`, it also throw an error:

```
Can't initialize rotatable log file :: caused by :: Failed to open D:\\MongoDB\\Server\\6.0\\log\\mongod.log
```

But this file also exist. (Should I delete it?) And no software is currently using this file, At least locksmith didn't detect any of them. **So MongoDB might got some problem with file system.**
[image]

I have already set 'storage.dbPath' option, and I can't find any mistakes in path or content of config file, and MongoDB just ignore it add try to fing a Data directory from root directory. I never even changed that file after I installed MongoDB, and this config file never work.

Comment: How do you start the MongoDB?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `mongod` command in Powershell, but the same command with Administrator privileges and/or in cmd also won't work.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Check the write permissions on these folders. Check in your service manager (or run in powershell `Get-Service mongo*`) if a MongoDB service exists and is running. You may try to start it twice.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I replaced images with texts, and there is a mongod service running, I think this problem has been solved, thanks for your help. but, how can I get access to this service?

Comment: I'm asking new bing for help, it said `Set-Service` can do this

Comment: Use `mongod --remove` and `mongod --install`, every config is done in the configuration file. Did you stop any running service? I don't see anything wrong in your installation check carefully every setting for typo.

Answer (score 0):

The config file is only used if you specify it. When you run just `mongod.exe` then no config file is used and all configuration use the default values.

If you use `mongod -f D:\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongod.cfg` then it should work, check the configuration file.

Usually you install MongoDB as a service, e.g.

```
mongod -f D:\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongod.cfg --install
```

Then it starts automatically when you the computer.

See [mongod.exe](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod.exe/)